# Does WCF ease implementing latex to pdf conversion web service?

Tags: wcf, service

I want to buy  a book on WCF because I need to develop latex to pdf conversion web service.

The idea is to let the customer submit latex documents (known as input file with .tex extension) to my web site and download the pdf output generated by the server helped by a service behind the scene.

I am new to WCF, so I have no idea, whether WCF can ease my development.

I am also considering the security issues such as protecting the server from any bad input.

Could you give me a suggestion whether or not WCF will suit my need?

EDIT 1: I am confused with choosing only one answer as both Martin's and Ben's really help me. Using classic probabilistic approach by throwing a coin, the result is Ben's. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF will neither help nor hinder your effort overmuch - it's designed to facilitate the actual plumbing of service routing and message handling.  The "business logic" (in this case, the latex->pdf conversion) is left to the programmer to implement themselves.  For a task with such a simple workflow, WCF would definitely be overkill.

If you had complex authentication requirements, WCF's security features would help you immensely, after a very steep learning curve.  I'd recommend sticking with a simple POST or something.  Your question about bad input is, again, outside of the scope of WCF.  You'll have to take care of that in your business logic.

That said, good luck - sounds like a fun project!

Comment: thanks for your helpful explanation. What is the rough idea to let an exe application (such as latex.exe) get executed as a single instance but can serve multiple users? Thank you in advance. A bit about my project: My project is to create web based math examination where teachers will submit the math problems in (La)TeX input file (*.tex) containing both equation "codes" and PostScript "codes". I know there is an plug-in named jsMath or Mathjax, but they cannot render PostScript images.

Comment: If you're set on .NET, I'd recommend looking at ASP.NET for your front-end, and maybe have Windows service running in the background perform the conversions, which you certainly don't want to run in the webserver itself!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think WCF will help much. For the service itself, I recommend to use form upload (ie. e regular HTML page with a regular form producing a regular POST); this can be done with any web framework, including asp.net.

For the protection against bad input, you'll have to define "bad input": what kind of threat could a Latex file pose? But regardless of the threat - WCF is not designed to help protecting your service from bad input; the security is rather designed to prevent unauthorized users from accessing your service (whether or not they then submit bad input).

Comment: thanks for your helpful response. Based on your explanation as well as @Ben's above, I am thinking of another way.